# Django parameter from views to forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to send a parameter from the view to the form with this code.
In the view I call the constructor:

```
    from = FormSet(request.POST or None, prefix='employee', id=id)
```

The id was given over the url. In the form I define the constructor like this:

```
    class FormSet(SearchForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                id = kwargs.pop('id')
            except KeyError:
                raise Http404
            super(FormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['employee'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all().filter(id=id))
```

And I got this error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

Do someone know the problem?

Comment: I don't think you are passing id to `ProbeForm` you are using `FormSet`

Comment: sorry my mistake it's FormSet in the forms too

Answer (score 0):

I had it once too, i solved it by using:

```
def __init__(self, id=None, *args, **kwargs):
```